# If you have any question(s)

Tags: grammar, determiners

What's the difference between the two following sentences? This site says **any** could also be used with singular nouns in *if clauses* when it means **any kind of**. Is it true? Are both following sentence correct?

- If you have **any questions**, please let me know.
- If you have **any question**, please let me know.

I know the first one correct. But according to this [site](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv303.shtml) the singular noun is also correct when It means **any kind of.**

Answer (score 5):

According to *Fowler's Dictionary of Modern English Usage*, which is a standard grammar reference book, the compounds that derive from the word "any" such as "anyone", "any way", "anyhow", "anymore" or the rare, "anywise" are all singular.

According to the *Oxford Learner's Dictionary*, [here](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/any_1?q=any):

"any" can be used with uncountable or plural nouns in questions

The Oxford Learner's Dictionary does recognize that "any" can be used with singular nouns when it does not matter which one, such as in:

```
Pick any card.
```

The website referred to in the query is correct.

There is a difference of meaning in the two examples stated in the query.

The first sentence,

```
If you have any questions, please let me know.
```

is something a teacher would ask a group of students in order to make sure an explanation is clear.

The second sentence,

```
If you have any question, please let me know.
```

would mean the same as the previous example if "a" was substituted for "any".  But as the sentence stands, it is a little unusual.  It could be understood to be regarding the questioning of a person's guilt or innocence.   "Doubt" would be a better word instead of "question" in this context.

The word "question" in the second sentence could be understood to mean "controversy", but this would also not be the usual construction.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it is correct.

"If you have *any* questions, please let me know."

In this sentence *any* means *some / several / more than one*

"If you have *any question* (whatsoever), please let me know."

Here *any question* can be replaced with *a question of any kind*
-> If you have *a question of any kind* please let me know.

Just like the article states, it is used for emphasis. It's a way to indicate importance. I believe, the reason to emphasize this is to encourage the listeners to ask questions. No matter how unimportant or minor their questions might appear to them, they still should ask away.